# Finder 40.61 relay coil current

Tags: microcontroller, relay

Does anyone know how much current this relay needs for its coil to turn on? And what's its coil resistance? Here is the datasheet: [Finder 40.61](https://www.finder-relais.net/en/finder-relays-series-40.pdf)
It's a 12v DC relay.
And how can I turn it on using a microcontroller PIN?

Comment: There are 25 variants of that relay including DC and AC coil versions. Which one do you want to use? What is the relay coil supply voltage going to be? [Edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: @Transistor Like I said, the relay is 40.61 and coil supply voltage is supposed to be 12 volts.

Comment: (1) How much coil current depends on input voltage.  Usually 5V needs 70mA, 12V needs less, for the same power (See reference below). (2) You can use a 3V3/5V0 MPU/SBC GPIO pin to turn on/off, with the help of a transistor, usually NPN BJT.  You also need a flyback diode, and an optocoupler, if environment is noisy. (3) Reference: My answer to this EESE Relay Q&A: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks

Comment: @Mono, your are welcome. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01. How would an opto help? Optos give galvanic isolation but can still couple fast transients due to their capacitance.

Comment: @Kartman, yes, I agree, but optoisolation is good enough in general industrial and medical applications.

Comment: @tlfong01 the relays themselves provide galvanic isolation between the coil and the contacts so the optos add little to the circuit - to exploit the galvanic isolation of the optos would require a separate isolated supply.

Comment: @Kartman, Well, there is (1) back EMF which travels through, conducting wires, including ground wiring, and (2) EMI which travels through air and space.  You might like to read my discussion below: (3) Ref: What is back EMF? EESE 2021apr17: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/562294/what-is-back-emf

Comment: @tlfong01 I'm no stranger to these effects. I don't need to tell you that a well placed diode negates these effects to a significant degree. The voltage is clamped and has a well defined path, so the opto will have little benefit. You've yet to convince me how in a circuit with a microcontroller and a relay would benefit from an opto in the relay drive in a correctly designed and laid out circuit.

Comment: @Kartman, Well, I hope this 8 year old EESE Q&A might convenience you.  (1) Why are relays so frequently driven by optocouplers? EESE Q&A, 2013feb27, Viewed 22k times
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59277/why-are-relays-so-frequently-driven-by-optocouplers.

Comment: @tlfong01 - i don't think that discussion uncovered anything new. Crap design = crap results. I think we'll stop the discussion here as there's nothing new to discover.

Comment: @Kartman, OK. Let us stop here. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. From datasheet.*

From \$ P = VI \$ we can calculate \$ I = \frac P V = \frac {0.65}{12} = 53\ \mathrm{mA} \$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs2scd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. An NPN switching circuit.*

Comment: Thank you. Can you also see what's the coil resistance?

Comment: Do you know the formula that relates power, voltage and resistance?

Comment: You are right. Thanks again.